# Fill screen horizontal and vertical with padding

Tags: html, css

I'm tearing my hair apart here. Does anyone know how i can get a div to fill the screen both horizontal and vertical? I can make it fill it horizontal but it just refuses to fill vertical unless a specify the width in pixels. What am I doing wrong?

This is what I want to accomplish, without have to scroll to get the bottom-padding:

[image: a full width and height div with padding on all sides]

Thank you!

HTML:

```
<div id="main">
    <div class="main_content"></div>
</div>​
```

CSS:

```
#main {
margin-left:auto;
margin-right:auto;
height:100%;
width:auto;
padding-left:40px;
padding-right:40px;
padding-top:40px;
padding-bottom:40px;
}

.main_content {
width:auto;
height:100%;
background:#fff;    
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you set a percentage height it is related to its container, that must have an explicit height. If you set height: auto, the container will take the height of its content. The parent of the div must have an explicit height property, you can set in 'px' or in 'em'. You can also set in 'vh'

Comment: Thank you! Is it possible to be done without setting the parent to a fixed height it 'px' or 'em'? All I want is a full with and height div with padding.

Comment: I think that in this case the best thing for you is to set the height of the div and the padding in 'vh'. For example height: 95vh and padding:5vh. In this way the div is widescreen

Comment: Works fine. Except that I have to scroll down to get the bottom-padding. Is there some way this can be solved without the scroll?

Comment: Do you mean that the pasding-bottom space appears only when you scroll down? Have you tried to reduce the height? If you have padding -top=padding-bottom = 5vh, height should be 100-5-5=90vh

Comment: Fabrizio, Your the man! Thank you so much! Works like a charm :) :) :)

Answer (score 1):

you can add `height:100vh;`

Demo : http://jsfiddle.net/6yLhk17h/

Comment: Hi, this doesn't give me the bottom-padding unless i scroll down. Any ideas how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Add the below code in your style sheet.

```
html{
    height: 100%;
}
```